# How to double escape html url parameters

Tags: html, url, escaping

I am trying to embed a SWF XML Flash chart into a web page. The chart uses xml generated by a dynamic JSP, specified via the xml_source parameter. In order to specify parameters to this JSP you have to escape the ?, & and space characters; since these characters are already used within the first part of the FlashVars string. My question is how do I escape these characters twice, since my parameter value might need to use & for parameters like job=Buyer & Designate.

```
     AC_FL_RunContent(
        'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,45,2',
        'width', '800',
        'height', '650',
        'scale', 'noscale',
        'salign', 'TL',
        'wmode', 'opaque',
        'movie', '/OA_MEDIA/charts',
        'src', '/OA_MEDIA/charts',
        'FlashVars', 'library_path=/OA_MEDIA/charts_library&xml_source=/OA_HTML/xxpay_salary_graph_xml.jsp%3Fjob%3DBuyer%20%26%20Designate%26nocache%3D6',
        'id', 'my_chart',
        'name', 'my_chart',
        'menu', 'true',
        'allowFullScreen', 'true',
        'allowScriptAccess', 'sameDomain',
        'quality', 'high',
        'align', 'middle',
        'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
        'play', 'true',
        'devicefont', 'false'
        );
```

It doesn't work if I do

```
xml_source=/OA_HTML/xxpay_salary_graph_xml.jsp%3Fjob%3DBuyer%20%26%20Designate%26nocache%3D6
```

or

```
xml_source=/OA_HTML/xxpay_salary_graph_xml.jsp%3Fjob%3DBuyer%20&%20Designate%26nocache%3D6
```

Is there another way of escaping that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

Any instance of `&` needs to be replaced with `&amp;`.

For example, `...%3DBuyer%20&%20Designate...` should be changed to `...%3DBuyer%20&amp;%20Designate...`.